# Push local new Git repo to existing remote repo as branch?

Tags: git, github

I have a situation where I completely re-wrote the code from scratch where we had current existing code on the remote repo.

I would like to push my local new repo master to that existing remote as a branch to merge it later upon review.

Remote git repo: A has branches a1, a2, a3

My local new repo: B

After my desired push to remote: A has branches a1, a2, a3, and ab

Is it even possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories

Comment: I suspect you will have to 1) clone the original repo 2) make a new branch 3) delete all files and commit 4) add all new files and commit 5) push new branch to remote

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure.  Just push it like this:

```
git push origin master:ab
```

This will push your local `master` branch to `ab` branch of the remote named `origin`.

Comment: It worked like a charm. Very simple solution. thanks