Push local repo into an existing remote repo as a branch
I have a scenario similar to what is asked in this question: Push local new Git repo to existing remote repo as branch?
The scenario is: I have a local repo A which I want to push to a remote repo B as a new branch. I do not want to merge, per se, but only create a new branch in the remote repo without losing history of repo A. Local repo A only has one branch called main.
The scenario looks as:
Local Repo A
Remote Repo B
Desired Result: Remote Repo B has branch named A
But the answer to this question (Push local new Git repo to existing remote repo as branch?) doesn't explain how to switch paths between repo A and repo B when executing the push.
I found another solution: How do you merge two Git repositories? (which has detailed steps listed in the answers) but I do not want to create a sub-directory but rather a branch from the local repo. I am thinking that there is some step that is missing from the following to make the repo A as a branch:
cd path/to/Repo-B
git remote add Repo-A /path/to/Repo-A
git fetch Repo-A --tags
git merge --allow-unrelated-histories Repo-A/master 
git remote remove Repo-A

Is there some way I can accomplish moving local repo to remote repo as a new branch and not lose any history?

You question is unclear. Do you have only one branch in the local repo? If there're more then 1 how do you plan to push them as a single branch? If you want to push only one branch — the 1st linked question has an accepted answer and the answer is your answer, just do it.

Yes I only have branch (called main). But the answer to the first linked question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32277448/push-local-new-git-repo-to-existing-remote-repo-as-branch) doesn't provide details as to whether I execute the push while being present in repo B and how do I tell git where repo A is? Or did you mean this question has the response: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories ?

"…details as to whether I execute the push while being present in repo B and how do I tell git where repo A is?" You completely confuse your A and B. The question should be written as "details as to whether I execute the push while being present in repo A and how do I tell git where repo B is?" No, I mean the first question (in your comment it's also the 1st).


whether I execute the push while being present in repo A

Yes. You cannot push without being in repo A. There're two (rather similar) ways. 1st, you can manually cd into required directory:
cd /path/to/A
git push

Or you can tell git to do this:
git -C /path/to/A push


how do I tell git where repo B is?

Example setup: local repo A with the single branch master. Remote repo B with URL http://host/user/repos/B. You want to push master from A to B as branch A. Again, there're two similar ways. 1st, you can push directly to the URL:
git -C /path/to/A push http://host/user/repos/B master:A

(master:A means "push local branch master to remote branch A"). If you gonna push only once this is the simplest way.
Or you can add a short alias (called "remote") and can use the alias to push many times:
cd /path/to/A
git remote add B http://host/user/repos/B
git push B master:A # <- push master:A to remote B


Thank you so much for such a detailed response. Yes, I was confused and your explanation wonderfully helped.

You can do this by following below two steps.

you have to change the local repo A remote url to remote repo B

From local repo A
git remote set-url origin <remote_Repo_B_git_url>


Then you can push this local repo A code into new branch in repo B (with branch name Repo_A)

git push origin <local_repo_A_branch>:Repo_A

Example
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:xxxx/yy.git
git push origin main:Repo_A


Why would you change the URL of the origin remote? Either create a new remote or simply push to the URL directly.

This answer would have been useful too but I didn't want to change the origin of my local repo.
